# What is the best way to present the following predictive regression relationship?

Tags: predictive-models, autoregressive, vector-autoregression

If I have a predictive regression with a single regressor of the form
\begin{equation}
y_t=\beta x_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t
\end{equation}
where 
\begin{equation}
x_t=\rho x_{t-1}+u_t
\end{equation}
Then I can present the above relationship as
\begin{equation}
y_t=\beta(\rho x_{t-2}+u_{t-1})+\varepsilon_t\quad\text{or}\quad y_t=\beta\rho x_{t-2}+\beta u_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t.
\end{equation}
Now instead say we have
\begin{equation}
y_t=B'X_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t
\end{equation}
where $B=(\beta_1,\cdots,\beta_k)'$ is a $k\times 1$ vector of coefficients and $X_t=(x_{1,t},\cdots,x_{k,t})'$ is a $k\times 1$ vector of stochastic variables, for $i=1,\cdots,k$, each following an AR($p_i$) process where the orders $p_i$ and $p_j$ are not necessarily the same. If I wish to represent this case in the same manner as with the example with one explanatory variable shown above in a compact manner using vectors/matrices, what is the best way to go about it? In other words, how can I express this in vector format. I initially thought of representing the AR($p_i$) processes as VAR($1$) processes and using stacking etc. But I have a feeling it must be much more straightforward than this.

Comment: Are you sure that don't mean to have $x_t$ in the first equation and not $x_{t-1}$ ? I think I've seen that case in the literature but not the one you've written. Of course, it could be the case that you're looking at something different from what I've seen in the literature.

Comment: In a predictive regression framework, it is indeed $x_{t-1}$. In this context the literature is vast and what I had been working for months. However, that is not the main issue. Once could assume that it is indeed $x_{t}$ instead of $x_{t-1}$. My  question would still remain unchanged (with the exception of the subscripts of course).

Comment: I can't help but have you looked at adbanced econometrics books. I think I've seen something like that in the context of autoregressive distributed lags but I've never deal with what you're trying to do in terms of stacking. I was always dealing with the univariate case.

Comment: Also, note that, by using $x_{t-1}$ in the first equation, $\beta$ is not identified even in the univariate case. I don't think that happens if one uses $x_t$ in the first equation. In your case, you'd have to define a new variable $\beta^{*} = \beta \rho$, estimate that model and then back out the original variables. Basically, estimate the reduced form and then  back out the structural parameter estimates.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. So a very good example (among many) in this context would be the paper "Efficient tests of stock return predictability" by Campbell and Yogo (2006) in JFE. Identification is not an issue, as the aim is more for hypothesis testing than estimation. So as the test is a Neyman-Pearson type test, $\beta$ is $0$ under the null hypothesis and $\beta_1$ under the alternative. So the only coefficient that requires estimation is $\rho$, which can be done so using an AR($1$) process. My issues is the presentation problem in my main question, not estimation/identification.

Comment: okay. thanks. I'll try to find what I'm talking about when I have a chance because I've seen something similar somewhere but it was a text rather than a paper. Good luck with what you're doing. I'll try to find the paper you referred to also.